# Trying to make a bitmap larger by width + factor, height + factor, using c

Tags: c

This is my code. My output is correct for only the first line of pixels. I have stretched the first line correctly horizontally, and the padding is right. But for the next lines, the padding is incorrect, and the pixels have not been stretched correctly vertically.

```
// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(oldHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{ 

    for (int l = 0; l < factor; l++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < oldWidth; j++)
        {    
             // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);


            for (int k = 0;k < factor;k++)
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);


            }


        }



    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, oldpadding, SEEK_CUR);

    // then add it back
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    if (i != factor)
    {
       fseek(inptr, -bi.biWidth-padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }


}

//structure of RBG struct
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: What's your input format? Is it 24bpp i.e. "rrggbbrrggbb...rrggbb"? How is RGBTRIPLE structured?

Comment: i updated to include RGB triple structure